# deleting elements from sorted list using "pop_front" leads to crash

Tags: c++

I need to delete first 3 items from sorted list, for this logic I can use 'erase' to delete elements. But, I want to know how 'pop_front' works for this case. Hence, I have tried below code, but it is crashing(corrupting iterator after one loop). I don't know why it is corrupting iterator in this case. Could someone help me on this.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    list<int> l;
    for (int i=1; i<=5; ++i)
    {
        l.push_back(i);
    } 

    for (list<int>::iterator itr=l.begin(); itr != l.end(); ++itr)
    {
        if(*itr <= 3)
          l.pop_front(); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Once you remove an element from the list, the iterator is no longer valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know why it is corrupting iterator in this case.

Just read [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/pop_front):

> References and iterators to the erased element are invalidated.

in the first iteration `itr` points to `l.begin()` which erased, then `++itr` on invalid iterator fails. You need to increase iterator before `pop_front()` called. But better you erase explicitly using iterator to avoid surprises:

```
for (list<int>::iterator itr=l.begin(); itr != l.end(); )
{
    if(*itr <= 3) l.erase( it++ );
    else ++it; 
}
```

This code may have different behavior than yours as you always delete the first element no matter where `itr` points to but I assume you wanted to delete elements less or equal than 3.

Answer (score 0):

So there's a few things going on here.

First: you're changing a list while iterating through it. Typically this is a bad idea to attempt. Consider list as a linked list. Each node consists of its own value and a pointer/reference to the next element. By popping an item you remove it from the list, then the iterator will no longer know where to look for the next element. It's actually a bit more complicated than this (each type of standard collection has certain defined operations that have to invalidate iterators, but they vary between collection types), but this is the general idea.

Second: you aren't removing elements with an index less than 3, you're trying to remove elements with a value less than 3. It would work logically in this case only because the first 3 elements have values 1, 2, and 3.

To fix your problem I would write your second loop like this:

```
for(int index=0; index<3; index++){
  l.pop_front();
}
```

And then you can iterate through the list later if there are other operations you need to perform.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response,

I think I found answer for question I asked for:

Answer: In for loop 'Initiating iterator with list begin' and in for loop block I am deleting 'first element of list using pop_front', once we delete first element list.begin() changes to next element in list. but still iterator is not. so it is becoming dangling pointer, and next we are accessing dangling pointer in next loop, Hence it is dumping code.

Found above informations through gdb.

```
Breakpoint 2, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdfd8) at list_erase.cpp:20
20      for (list<int>::iterator itr=l.begin(); itr != l.end(); ++itr)
(gdb) n
22          if(*itr <= 3)
(gdb) p *itr
$5 = (int &) @0x603020: 1
(gdb) p itr
$6 = {_M_node = 0x603010}
(gdb) p l.begin()
$7 = {_M_node = 0x603010}
(gdb) n
23              l.pop_front();
(gdb) n
20      for (list<int>::iterator itr=l.begin(); itr != l.end(); ++itr)
(gdb) p itr
$8 = {_M_node = 0x603010}
(gdb) p l.begin()
$9 = {_M_node = 0x603030} 
(gdb) n
22          if(*itr <= 3)
(gdb) p itr
$10 = {_M_node = 0x0}
(gdb) p l.begin()
$11 = {_M_node = 0x603030}
```

To fix my problem through 'pop_front', I should do like below:

```
 for (list<int>::iterator itr=l.begin(); itr != l.end(); )
 {
    if(*itr <= 3)
    {
       l.pop_front();
       itr = l.begin();
       //  OR
       // itr = l.erase(l.begin()); 
    }else
       ++itr;
 }
```

'pop_front work like this' :
Since, std::list pop_front implemented like below:

```
 void pop_front() { erase(begin()); }
```

And in pop_front code implementation, we are not catching return value of next element of list, so after it erase it will be dangling pointer. So, crash expected.

Let me know, If am wrong..